# Move database without replication taking new snapshot

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

We are upgrading a physical server we have SQL installed on at work, and I need to move SQL to a new machine, but I need to do it with minimum downtime.

I have the new virtual server already available to me, so I was going to setup log shipping from the Old -> new server to handle the actual move of the database(s) -- The server also has replication coming from a different server (the database I am moving is the subscriber).  How could I get the replication moved from the old to new without having to re-initialize replication?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered setting up a subscription on the upgraded / new server and then repointing whichever application at the new subscriber database overnight?